# Workaround clang warning -Wambiguous-member-template

Tags: c++, templates, clang

How can I workaround this clang warning? This appears quite frequently with code that includes STL `<set>` and additionally has a templatized `set()` function.

I don't want to disable the warning globally, but also not manually for every file where `<set>` is included (too many).

```
template<typename T> struct set{};
template<typename T> struct trait { typedef const T& type; };
struct Value {
  template<typename T> void set(typename trait<T>::type value) {}
};
void foo() {
  Value v;
  v.set<double>(3.2);
}
```

```
clang.cpp:8:9: warning: lookup of 'set' in member access expression is ambiguous; using member of 'Value' [-Wambiguous-member-template]
      v.set(3.2);
        ^
clang.cpp:4:29: note: lookup in the object type 'Value' refers here
  template void set(typename trait::type value) {}
                ^
clang.cpp:1:29: note: lookup from the current scope refers here
template struct set{};
                ^
1 warning generated.
```

The obvious solution would be to not use templatized `set()` methods but that seems rather limiting.

Comment: What about a proper use of namespaces and avoiding using namesspace std?

Comment: Which version of clang are you using?

Comment: @DyP: release_34 from SVN

Comment: @MartinRichtarsky I think the whole issue has been resolved in [DR 1111](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1111), which has FDIS status - AFAIK it's part of the Standard now. So you should interpret the warning as *ill-formed in C++03, allowed and unambiguous now*. Understanding that, you might want to disable the warning as suggested by n.m.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning appears to be invalid. The standard [basic.lookup.classref] doesn't seem to indicate there's an ambiguity, or require any diagnostic, in such  cases. Here's the relevant passage:

1. In a class member access expression (5.2.5), if the `.` or `->` token is immediately followed by an identifier followed by a `<`, the identifier must be looked up to determine whether the `<` is the beginning of a template
   argument list (14.2) or a less-than operator. The identifier is first looked up in the class of the object
   expression. If the identifier is not found, it is then looked up in the context of the entire postfix-expression
   and shall name a class template.

I would disable the warning globally.

Comment: There seems to have been a change between n3242 and n3337, between which the Standard has been published. n3242 requires an error in this case, but more recent versions do not. n3242 [basic.lookup.classref]/1, bullet 3: "if the name found is a class template, it shall refer to the same entity as the one found in the class of the object expression, otherwise the program is ill-formed."

Comment: @dyp this is a C++03 rule which was fixed in C++1 [see my answer here for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52638779/1708801) and yes it is pretty wacky.

Answer (score 2):

You're right, the obvious solution is not to define **conflicting** template `set` methods and classes. The name lookup rules in your scope must not be ambiguous between the class and the method, i.e. the symbol `set` must not refer to both, you must use namespaces to disambiguate.

You probably don't define the `set` method in namespace `std`, so I can only assume you injected `std::set` in your scope, with `using std::set` or `using namespace std`.

Generally, `using namepsace std` if a bad idea, because you don't control the symbols it injects in your scope (depends on recursive includes), and you don't always control with what other symbols this may conflict.

In your case, as Dieter said, the simplest solution is to stop `set` from referring to `std::set` by removing relevant `using` clauses. You'd then have to use `std::set` to name it, instead of just `set` but there no longer would be any conflict.

Comment: Makes sense. The codebase is guilty of too much `using`s, but it will take a while to clean them up.