# Ambiguous member template lookup

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, function-call, name-lookup

An answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877687/c-template-gotchas) says in the following code:

```
#include <vector>
using std::vector;

struct foo {
  template<typename U>
  void vector();
};

int main() {
  foo f;
  f.vector<int>(); // ambiguous!
}
```

The last line in main is ambiguous, because the compiler not only looks up `vector` within `foo`, but also as an unqualified name starting from within `main`. So it finds both `std::vector` and `foo::vector`. To fix this, you have to write

```
f.foo::vector<int>();
```

I've tried this program on all popular C++ compilers ( `g++`, `clang++`, `vc++` and Intel C++ ) and all compilers compile this program without any error. So, why did he say that there is ambiguity in this program ? What does the C++ standard say about this ?

Comment: It's a very old answer.  Compilers (and the language itself) have evolved since then.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm: If compilers and language itself have evolved I would like to know the old rules and new rules that cause this change.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was the case in C++03 but this was fixed in C++11. We can even try this [live in godbolt with clang using -std=c++03 flag](https://godbolt.org/z/bdGwRX). We do receive a warning:

```
<source>:11:5: warning: lookup of 'vector' in member access expression is ambiguous; using member of 'foo' [-Wambiguous-member-template]

  f.vector<int>(); // ambiguous!
    ^
```

Older clang documentation [using the same example from the defect report below](http://releases.llvm.org/5.0.0/tools/clang/docs/UsersManual.html#cmdoption-Wambiguous-member-template) when describing the warning for `-Wambiguous-member-template`.

This was changed via [defect report 1111: Remove dual-scope lookup of member template names](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1111)  which explains the issue:

> According to 6.4.5 [basic.lookup.classref] paragraph 1,
>
> > In a class member access expression (8.2.5 [expr.ref]), if the . or -> token is immediately followed by an identifier followed by a <,
> >     the identifier must be looked up to determine whether the < is the
> >     beginning of a template argument list (17.2 [temp.names]) or a
> >     less-than operator. The identifier is first looked up in the class of
> >     the object expression. If the identifier is not found, it is then
> >     looked up in the context of the entire postfix-expression and shall
> >     name a class template. If the lookup in the class of the object
> >     expression finds a template, the name is also looked up in the context
> >     of the entire postfix-expression and
> >
> > - if the name is not found, the name found in the class of the object expression is used, otherwise
> > - if the name is found in the context of the entire postfix-expression and does not name a class template, the name found
> >       in the class of the object expression is used, otherwise
> > - if the name found is a class template, it shall refer to the same entity as the one found in the class of the object expression,
> >       otherwise the program is ill-formed.
>
> This makes the following ill-formed:
>
> ```
> #include <set>
> using std::set;
> struct X {
>   template <typename T> void set(const T& value);
> };
> void foo() {
>   X x;
>   x.set<double>(3.2);
> }
> ```
>
> That's confusing and unnecessary. The compiler has already done the
>   lookup in X's scope, and the obviously-correct resolution is that one,
>   not the identifier from the postfix-expression's scope. Issue 305
>   fixed a similar issue for destructor names but missed member
>   functions.

Comment: What does it mean when it says that _not the identifier from the postfix-expression's scope_ ?

Comment: @Destructor IIUC it is referring to `If the lookup in the class of the object expression finds a template, the name is also looked up in the context of the entire postfix-expression`